# database memory wastage after deletion

Tags: mysql, memory-management, auto-increment

i have 30 or even more than this tables and all tables have their primary key set to auto-increment so whenever i perform delete operation like deleting  30 records from 10 tables then after deletion 300 memory cells will always remain blank because primary keys are set to auto-increment.So think of this same situation for very large databases,so how to solve this problem and reuse those memory cells again.

Comment: AFAIK auto-increment is just a counter. It has nothing to do with memory. The fact that the PK column is not a full mathematical series has no bearing on performance at all. The only thing delete has an effect on is the rollback log. In case you are deleting all the data in a table, it is better to truncate it.

Comment: i am not deleting all the data and if pk is just a counter than how actually memory management takes place?

Comment: The mysql memory model is a complex thing. The row collection, in regards to the PK, is sparce i.e. missing values do not take up any memory. Read here for more information about mysql memory management: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html

Comment: thanx for the answer...this means memory management takes place internally but now my query is what should i do if i want to use the same pk again like i deleted records having pk between 20-30 then my records after 30 i.e from 31 to so on will have same pk's and pk's from 20-30 are now not used by any row so what to do if i want that my records from 31 to so on should now start from 20 rather than 31

Comment: The idea with auto-increment is just that, to auto-increment. It just goes on and on. Even if older numbers are not used any more. If this does not meet your requirments, maybe auto-increment is not right for you. Maybe you need to manage your own numbering scheme. If this is just a matter of "waste", it`s ok. That`s just how databases work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its auto incremented already so you cant help it.there is no memory wastage in this.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key does not refer to any sort of "memory cells" it's just a counter to give each row a unique number.

Theoretically it would be possible to use all the possible keys, I'm unsure however if MySQL would attempt to use old values which have been deleted (it shouldn't). But considering an unsigned BIGINT field can goes up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (18 quintillion), it's unlikely you'd ever run into an issue with it.

Comment: okk accepted if we take bigint i will never run out of space but what if i want to use the same pk again what should i do?

Comment: @rupinder18 Idealy you shouldn't ever use the same primary key again. A primary key is commonly referenced in other tables. If you were to use it again you would risk associating it with data that it shouldn't be. An auto-incrementing primary key should not be a value you care about. If you want to change it/manually assign it I wouldn't recommend auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment is just a counter. It has nothing to do with memory. The fact that the PK column is not a full mathematical series has no bearing on performance at all. The only thing delete has an effect on is the rollback log. In case you are deleting all the data in a table, it is better to truncate it.

The mysql memory model is complex. For an overview you can look at [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html) from the mysql development documentation.